# I have a trouble about a SQL instruction on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

I have the follow instruction on PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTOR(
    ACT_CUIL            NUMERIC(8,0) NOT NULL,
    ACT_NOMBRE      CHARACTER VARYING(25) NOT NULL,
    ACT_APELLIDOPAT     CHARACTER VARYING(25) NOT NULL,
    ACT_APELLIDOMAT     CHARACTER VARYING(25) NOT NULL,
    ACT_NOMARTCO            CHARACTER VARYING(25) NULL,
    ACT_ROL         CHARACTER VARYING(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY             (ACT_CUIL),
    FOREIGN KEY            (ID_ELEN)  REFERENCES ELENCO(ID_ELEN)

);
```

The Primary Key from ACTOR is created; but the pgAdmin compiler says me:

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "actor_pkey" for table "actor"
ERROR:  column "id_elen" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist


********** Error **********

ERROR: column "id_elen" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
SQL state: 42703
```

About this I don't know what is the problem. I use the official documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html

Thanks 
Regards

Comment: The field `id_elen` does not exist in the **ACTOR** table. (it could have been `ACT_ID_ELEN`, but even that does not exist.

Comment: thanks wildplasser, but how can I declare a table with simple fields and then apply changes at the foreing key?. In the link that I share with you, says that I can't to use ALTER TABLE by example like MySQL.Thanks.

Comment: You misunderstood. The construct `FOREIGN KEY abx references klm(xyz)` assumes that 1) the column abc exists in this table 2) table klm exist and 3) table klm contains a column xyz (with the correct column type). In your case, column abc does not exist. BTW: your link points to a postges 8.1 manpage, which is outdated. I fail to see the relevance of ALTER TABLE here.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the id_elen column doesn't exist in ELENCO table.

Comment: that's ok but; that's incredible PostgreSQL says to me that really exits and that id_elen is a Primary Key

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a table "elenco" with at least on field - id_elen.
Does this table exist?

Otherwise a foreign relation is not allowed.